# sending confirm email if email is changed in usersettings with symfony mailer

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, mailer

I am trying to send an email if the user is changeing his email. but I don´t know hot to tell the eventhandler when to send the email.[Symfony Mailer Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27htK.png)

Now the email is send when a PUT request is send but i only should be send if the email is changed.

Comment: we need to see your code, that handles data submitted by user. And please include your code as an actual text into your question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in API Platform Event Subscriber, you can access the object before new data are hydrated with `$event->getRequest()->attributes->get('previous_data')`.

Comment: do not forget to vote for my answer please @Karim